# mongoDB group query not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

So, I have the following query on my routes page:

```
const testeEa = atendimentos.aggregate([
            {$group : {_id: "$id_atendente", Idcount:{$sum:1}}},
            {$sort: {_id: 1}},
            { '$group': {
                    '_id': null,
                    'eatest': {
                        '$sum': {
                            '$cond' : [ { '$eq': ['$status', 'EA'] },  1, 0]
                            }
                        },
                    //'eatest': {'$push': "$$ROOT"}
                } }
        ]).exec();
```

What I want to do is: This Idcount is counting how many times id_atendente repeats. I need this to check out how many support calls each person answered.

After this is done, I need to check all the support calls with the 'EA' status.

I have 351 calls with the 'EA' status, and I would like to see who is with this status on the support call.

I guess that I'm missing something on the second $group, I just don't what it is.

This eatest is supposed to be the key that will be used on the view.

By the way, I managed to do a query where I can get the number of support calls per id, I need almost the same thing, the difference is that I only need the ones with the 'EA' status.

**EDIT 1**

```
const counts = atendimentos.aggregate([
            { '$group': {
                    '_id': null,
                    'fin': {
                        '$sum': {
                            '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$status', 'F' ] }, 1, 0 ]
                        }
                    },
                    'ea': {
                        '$sum': {
                            '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$status', 'EA' ] }, 1, 0 ]
                        }
                    }
                } }
        ]).exec()

    //Faz uma consulta no mongo e guarda o resultado
    //na variável monthly
    const monthly = atendimentos.aggregate([
        { '$group': {
                '_id': {
                    'year': { '$year': '$date' },
                    'month': { '$month': '$date' }
                },
                'sum': { '$sum':  1 }
            } },
        {  '$group': {
                '_id': null,
                //Chave usada para renderizar os dados
                'back': { '$push':  '$$ROOT' }
            } },
    ]).exec();

    //Verificar quantas vezes um id_atendente se repete, contar e guardar o numero
    const testeAt = atendimentos.aggregate([
     {$group : {_id: "$id_atendente", Idcount:{$sum:1}}},
        {$sort: {_id: 1}},
        { '$group': {
            '_id': null,
                //Chave usada para renderizar os dados
                'test': {'$push': "$$ROOT"}
            } },
    ]).exec();

    const atendente = atendimentos.aggregate([
        { '$group' : {
                '_id': "$id_atendente",
                'Idcount': { '$sum': 1 }
            } },
        { '$sort': { '_id': 1 } }
    ]).exec();

    const testeEa = atendimentos.aggregate([
        { '$group': {
                '_id': null,
                'eatest': {
                    '$sum': {
                        '$cond' : [ { '$eq': ['$status', 'EA'] },  1, 0]
                    }
                }
            } }
    ]).exec();

Promise.all([counts, monthly, testeAt, testeEa]).then(([counts, monthly, testeAt, testeEa]) => {
```

Notice that the atendente query and the testeAt are almost the same.

What I would like to do is use this testeEa variable to store the returned value of the queries that return the number of 'EA' status per id_atendente.

If I use try catch I can't do it I guess because the testeEa would be inside of it, and I wouldn't be ble to pass it to my array.

The eatest is returning the correct value by the way.

**END OF EDIT**

**EDIT 2**

An example of the data that I want, this is the query that it's working for checking number of calls/id.

```
{
            "_id": 42,
            "Idcount": 3
        },
        {
            "_id": 43,
            "Idcount": 155
        },
        {
            "_id": 46,
            "Idcount": 69
        },
        {
            "_id": 47,
            "Idcount": 16
        },
        {
            "_id": 48,
            "Idcount": 4
        },
        {
            "_id": 49,
            "Idcount": 21
        },
        {
            "_id": 50,
            "Idcount": 4
        },
```

This is exactly the way that I want, but the difference is that I want only the ones with the 'EA' status.

Idcount would be the number of how many times an id with the 'EA' status appears.

**END OF EDIT 2**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update the post to include the expected json response ?

Comment: Updated the question with the expected json

Answer (score 0):

When executing a pipeline in the aggregation framework, MongoDB pipes operators into each other. 
"Pipe" here takes the Linux meaning: *the output of an operator becomes the input of the following operator*. The result of each operator is a new collection of documents. 
So when Mongo executes the above pipeline, the results from the first two steps

```
{ '$group' : { /* First pipeline step */
    '_id': "$id_atendente", 
    'Idcount': { '$sum': 1 }
} },
{ '$sort': { '_id': 1 } } /* Second pipeline step */
```

will be an array of documents with the schema (for example):

```
[
    { _id: 'fuzz', IdCount: 2 },
    { _id: 'foo', IdCount: 9 },
    { _id: 'bar', IdCount: 4 },
    ....
]
```

Now when it executes the third pipeline

```
{ '$group': {
    '_id': null,
    'eatest': {
    '$sum': {
        '$cond' : [ { '$eq': ['$status', 'EA'] },  1, 0]
        }
    }
} }
```

the documents from the previous pipeline are piped into this pipeline expecting documents with a field called status which does not exist hence
the results wont be correct.

You need to run multiple aggregate pipelines in parallel and this can only be achieved in a single query with **[`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#pipe._S_facet)**:

### Using MongoDB 3.4.4 and above:

```
atendimentos.aggregate([
    { '$facet': {
        'atendente': [
            { '$group' : {
                '_id': "$id_atendente", 
                'Idcount': { '$sum': 1 }
            } },
            { '$sort': { '_id': 1 } }
        ],
        'eatest': [
            { '$group': {
                '_id': null,
                'eatest': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond' : [ { '$eq': ['$status', 'EA'] },  1, 0]
                    }
                }
            } }
        ]
    } }
]).exec((err, result) => console.log(result));
```

### Using MongoDB 3.2 and below:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const atendente = await atendimentos.aggregate([
            { '$group' : {
                '_id': "$id_atendente", 
                'Idcount': { '$sum': 1 }
            } },
            { '$sort': { '_id': 1 } }
        ]).exec();

        const eatest = await atendimentos.aggregate([
            { '$group': {
                '_id': null,
                'eatest': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond' : [ { '$eq': ['$status', 'EA'] },  1, 0]
                    }
                }
            } }
        ]).exec();

        const data = { atendente, eatest };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

**or with Promise API**

```
(() => {

    const atendente = atendimentos.aggregate([
        { '$group' : {
            '_id': "$id_atendente", 
            'Idcount': { '$sum': 1 }
        } },
        { '$sort': { '_id': 1 } }
    ]).exec();

    const eatest = atendimentos.aggregate([
        { '$group': {
            '_id': null,
            'eatest': {
            '$sum': {
                '$cond' : [ { '$eq': ['$status', 'EA'] },  1, 0]
                }
            }
        } }
    ]).exec();

    Promise.all([atendente, eatest]).then(([ atendente, eatest ]) => {
        const data = { atendente, eatest };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Hmm okay, that makes sense. Is there a way that I can do this try, catch and throw the eatest outside of the scope? So I can use it on the Promise.all method

Comment: Not sure I follow but I have added an example that uses `Promise.all`

Comment: I did the two queries and put them into the promise, but I'm still not getting the results to render. I may be confusing something with my key, I don't know for sure,

Comment: Is the query possible using $project?